# VSCode gulpfile.js and tsconfig.json for AngularJS and Typescript application

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have just started using VS Code and I would like to find out where I can find a `gulpfile.js` and a `tsconfig.json` that will let me watch the TS and the Less files and compile them on the fly.

I watched John Papa's presentation and also [this webinar](http://www.johnpapa.net/visual-studio-code-webinar/). It mentions that he has modified the HotTowel application for Typscript but nowhere can I find any examples of what the gulpfile should look like.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can share any examples with the community as an answer to this question. Even better it would be great if someone could point me to some sample applications that run under VSCode that have a gulpfile.js that I could work from.

Comment: I think you mean this sample from John Papa... https://github.com/johnpapa/hottowel-angular-typescript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your question, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to solve. Have you used gulp before? Are you just having issues getting it to work in VSCode or are you learning how to use Gulpjs? If you have used Gulpjs before, have you used watches? I have an example that works for the TS files. I believe this will set you in the right direction.

If you have a project structure like this:

```
project
  .settings
    tasks.json
    tsconfig.json
  src
    app.ts
  package.json
  gulpfile.js
```

tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "default",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent"
        }
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": "true",
        "removeComments": "true",
        "target": "ES5"
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts"
    ]
}
```

package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-concepts",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-typescript": "latest",
    "gulp-watch": "latest"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compileTypescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var tsProject = compileTypescript.createProject('./.settings/tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('compile-ts', function() {
    return tsProject.src() // instead of gulp.src(...) 
               .pipe(compileTypescript(tsProject))
               .js
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compile-ts'], function() {
        return gulp.watch(['./src/app.ts'], ['compile-ts']);
});
```

You will have to have npm installed on your box(which is part of the node.js install). You will need to navigate to your project directory(in a command prompt) and type *npm install*.

Once all of the npm modules are installed you should be able to type *Ctrl+Shift+B* in your VSCode window. The project should build and place an app.js file in a dest directory(if it wasn't previously created, this should create it). You can make changes to your app.ts file and once you save your changes you should see the app.js get regenerated.

The gulp.watch command takes an array of file paths to watch for changes as its first parameter and an array of gulp commands to rerun when any of those changes are detected.

You can look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less/) for how to setup less with your gulp build process. I don't know if you would want to watch all of those files at once or if you would like to setup two different watch tasks based on which one you are working on at a time(ts vs less). I hope this helps!

Also, this will create a long running task. I'm unsure how to terminate this task from VSCode. What I currently do is run *Ctrl+Shift+B* and it will give you a little prompt at the top of the VSCode editor saying that a task is already running and let you terminate the task from there. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: A tsconfig file specifies what files to compile.  So `gulp.src(['./src/app.ts'])` ideally wouldn't be necessary.  Gulp should read what source files to use from the tsconfig.  Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I have updated the gulpfile.js and the tsconfig.json file to answer your question, but that should be pretty apparent from the documenation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#using-tsconfig-json

Comment: For the _Less_ part of the problem, I've written a small Less -> CSS extension that auto-compiles on save without the need for a build task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrcrowl.easy-less